# FactoryGirl id not primary_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, factory-bot

I have a model that has a primary_id that is the actual primary_key, and an id column that is not auto_increment and cannot be null

In FactoryGirl, I have :

```
sequence(:primary_id) {|n| n}
sequence(:id) {|n| n}
```

but when I try to run it I get

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Column 'id' cannot be null: ...
```

with the record that is trying to be inserted having no id column set. 
I have seen in other questions that this is because ActiveRecord's write will automatically use :id to use the primary_key. If it is not an option to override this, or change column names, what's the 'proper' way to get FactoryGirl working?

Answer (score 1):

Do not rely on ids. Your factory rather should look like:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :foo do
    primary_id { 1 }
  end
end
```

Please also read one of the FactoryGirl tutorials out there, for example: [FactoryGirl Tips and Tricks](http://arjanvandergaag.nl/blog/factory_girl_tips.html)

Comment: Unfortunately this has to do with an existing schema. Thanks for looking out in terms of best practice, but moving away from using the id will likely not change and my question is about how to access the id column despite rails deciding to turn the :id key into the primary_key. The id is not automatically set, but must not be null so ignoring it is not a choice.